# Cannot kill local Jenkins on port 8080

Tags: macos, jenkins, localhost, port, kill-process

I have a local instance of Jenkins running on port 8080 on my mac machine. I want to kill this process and have tried doing so, like below :

```
lsof -i tcp:8080
kill -9 <the pid>
```

This closes my chrome instance. But when I open Chrome again and go to `localhost:8080`, Jenkins is still running over there. Any ideas as to why these commands don't kill it? Also how to kill the process?

Thanks

Comment: Because you kill Chrome, not Jenkins.

Comment: This. Jenkins running as a service? `service jenkins status` or `systemctl status jenkins`

Comment: I had the same problem.  Every time I would kill the jenkins process, it would restart.  The answer for me was here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272657/how-can-i-kill-the-jenkins-process

Answer (score 3):

Try using the below :

1. Try to identify the Jenkins instance/process id , like something below:

   ps -ef| grep jenkins
2. Go to the server (like apache) where your Jenkins is installed and kill the process id  like below :

   $ kill -9 1001(processId)

Answer (score 1):

`lost -i tcp:8080` will also list processes that connect to port 8080, e.g. chrome. What happens if you repeat above commands after you've quit chrome? Then hopefully Jenkins should be the only process working on port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Jenkins via the OSX Installer you'll need to follow [these instructions](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer) to edit the plist file via the command line (manually doing it is a pain).

When you've made necessary changes, such as running

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpPort [YOUR DESIRED PORT HERE]`

you'll need to 'unload' Jenkins:

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`.

And now Jenkins is dead. To undead Jenkins just swap **load** for **unload** in the above command.